# What does $\arg(z-z_1)-\arg(z-z_2)=\phi$ represents.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, locus

What does $\arg(z-z_1)-\arg(z-z_2)=\phi$ represents.

where $z$ is point in argand plane

**My Doubt:**
I am attaching a Image for the doubt because I don't know How to draw in latex. I'll be grateful if you can tell me how to do that.

I am considering $z_1$ is right of $z_2$

I've drawn $4$ diagram for locus. Can you tell me Are the arrow marked for angle by me are correct?

Also you can give me more information If you have.

Also locus of $z$ will be full circle or half circle if $\phi$  is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. If it is full circle what will be arrow mark for angle.

[image]

Comment: The locus is a part-circle, depending on the values of $z_1$, $z_2$ and $\phi$

Comment: It depends a bit on how you define $\arg$, as an equivalence class or a real number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding My Own Answer

Here I'm Attaching two Images in which I've plotted Locus of $z$ because I don't know how to plot them Digitally.
Arrow Must end at $(z-z_1)$ and must originate from $z-z_2$.

Also I am considering Principle Argument that is $(-\pi,\pi]$.
[image]

[image]