# Confusion in defining region between regions of complex rays relationships.

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, area, locus

> The following problem came up while attempting to answer the following: [What does $arg(z-z_1) - arg(z-z_2) = \phi$ represents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4655749/what-does-argz-z-1-argz-z-2-phi-represents). While, OP themselves tried a different method, one could interpret the equation as relationship (region) between $2$ rays within the complex plane.

Let us start of with the simplest case, $z_1, z_2 = 0$.

Hence, the relation $\arg(z - z_1) - \arg(z - z_2) = \phi$ would look like:

[image: z_1, z_2 = 0]

The confusion occurs when  $z_1, z_2 ≠ 0$. Given $z_1, z_2$ are arbritary, I am able two formulate to different scenarios as shown below

$\mathbb{\text{Fig. 1}}$

[image: Figure 1]

$\mathbb{\text{Fig. 2}}$

[image: Figure 2]

Reason for Figure 1; The relationship only restricted the angular region, which is dimensionless, but never restricted points below $z_1, z_2$, hence shaded region stays the same regardless of the ray translation.

Reason for Figure 2; The shaded region is defined by the ray arguments itself, which does not exist if the ray relationship does not exist below $z_1, z_2$.

I am unable to see which one is correct.

Comment: Do you understand what happens when $z_1=0$?

Comment: @coudy Hi! I assume the translation of the ray is $0$?

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm Attaching two Images in which I've plotted Locus of $z$ because I don't know how to plot them Digitally.
Arrow Must end at $(z-z_1)$ and must originate from $z-z_2$.

Also I am considering Principle Argument that is $(-\pi,\pi]$.
[image]

[image]

Comment: are you a jee aspirant? For 2023?

Comment: @ElizabethHuffman Yes

Comment: Good...I too. Best wishes.

Comment: Best wishes to you too...